# Configuring multiple ORGs in SalesForce Mobile sdk for login

Tags: mobilesdk

I am working on an app where we use Sales Force SDK for Login. We use 
**com.salesforce.mobilesdk:SalesforceSDK:5.+** SDK for login.

We currently have configured login url, oauthRedirectURI, Consumer key and client secret in servers.xml and bootconfig.xml for ORG1. How do we configure the same for ORG2 as the requirement is to configure the app to allow login using Sales Force SDK for both ORG1 and ORG2

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many Orgs you have the app should only have one connected app (consumer key, redirect uri, etc).  All you need to do is add the second Org to servers.xml.  Doc:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_custom_login_host.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_custom_login_host_ios.htm

Both orgs will show up on the connections screen (gear in the top right of the login screen) and allow you to login to either.  Multiple users can be logged-in to different Orgs simultaneously.

While not required, I would recommend upgrading the SDK as 5.3 is more than 2 years old.  8.0 was released yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for the help Brandon. As suggested by you, I have tried adding the second org to servers.xml with out changing the consumer key, redirect uri etc, but it didn't work. Aslo i will have to use SDK 5.3 as i need to support Android 4.4 as well. In the login screen i am not able to see the gear in the top right of the login screen to allow to login. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMWS9NEQ6cDfUdNtafhecmNOvKRTQ2c7/view

Comment: Apologies, I am out of the office this week.  The gear icon only shows on iOS.  For Android you should have a 3 dot menu in the top right with the option to "Change Server".    Unfortunately I am unable to see an image from the google drive link you provided.

Comment: I just tried again and I am able to see the login image.  That looks like a community login page but it is not being presented by the Mobile SDK.  If it was presented by the Mobile SDK it would look very similar to your desktop Salesforce login page but would have a blue bar across the top with the three dot menu I described earlier.  Much like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQSIo.png